# Light, stop using Nodes?

Tags: lighting, shader-nodes

After clicking "Use Nodes", how do I "unuse" Nodes, other than pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the light, open the shader editor and clear the *Use Nodes Checkbox*

[image: Shader editor showing use nodes highlighted]

This won't delete the node tree but will stop using nodes.

You can open the shader editor by going to the dropdown menu in the upper corner of the 3D Viewport, clicking and selecting *Shader Editor*. (shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>F3</kbd>)

[image: Editor type menu showing Shader Editor]

or you can switch to the *Shading* tab in the top bar menu.  The Shading editor will be the bottom editor.